# Next.js 13 - Huge Static file is slowing down development by a lot (Page.js is 31MB)

Tags: webpack, next.js, next.js13

I am having a huge issue when it comes to my development work with Next.js 13. I am using app folder and my team and I noticed how slow certain pages takes to load, which is pretty annoying so to say. In my network tab it says the size of page.js and layout.js is astonishing 31MB's, which is a quite lot. Did anyone else had a similar issue?

[image]

Here is my next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  productionBrowserSourceMaps: false,
  optimizeFonts: false,
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },

  webpack(config) {
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) =>
      rule.test?.test?.('.svg'),
    )

    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        ...fileLoaderRule,
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        resourceQuery: /url/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: fileLoaderRule.issuer,
        resourceQuery: { not: [...fileLoaderRule.resourceQuery.not, /url/] },
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
    )

    fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/i

    return config
  },
}

export default nextConfig
```

I tried changing the next.config.js to see where the issue is but I couldnt have figured what the issue is. I first thought that the issue is with my layout.tsx but I do not know what is wrong here, can someone see any issue here:

```
import { Plus_Jakarta_Sans } from 'next/font/google'
import { dir } from 'i18next'
import { Parameters } from '@/types/i18n'
import GeneralLayout from '@/components/layout/general-layout'
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'

import '../../styles/globals.scss'

const plusjakartasans = Plus_Jakarta_Sans({
  weight: ['400', '700', '800'],
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--plus-jakarta-sans-ff',
})

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  params,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
  params: Parameters
}) {
  if (!params.locale) return notFound()

  return (
    <html lang={params.locale ?? 'en'} dir={dir(params.locale ?? 'en')}>
      <head>
        <link
          rel='stylesheet'
          type='text/css'
          href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css'
        />
        <link
          rel='stylesheet'
          type='text/css'
          href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css'
        />
      </head>
      <body className={plusjakartasans.className}>
        <GeneralLayout>{children}</GeneralLayout>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```